# jquery .load() external content failed in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, bootstrap-modal

I try to load an external block of html through .load() jquery function, but it fails to render properly in a modal popup (note: same issue with .get() )

code is :

```
 $('#butt2').on('click', function() {
    $('#mbodyko').load('nav.html', function() {
        $('#myModalnok').modal({show: true });
      });
    });
```

Render is bad, here is the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/z9oQPVG2F9oYaJCzovN5?p=preview

You can notice that the tabs inside the second modal are not clickable, whereas the same html code renders well in the first modal.

Do you know why ? 
Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Don't use duplicate IDs ... JS always execute the first DOM or not execute or throw errors if use duplicate IDs... In your code whenever you click the 2nd modal links, its executing the tabs on 1st one...

Comment: @Karthik Indeed! I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did to make it work is removing out the first modal html, like this:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="butt1">modal OK</button>
<br />
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="butt2">modal NOK - use jquery .load</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalnok" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Problem: click does not change the tabs!</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body" id="mbodyko">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
      $('#butt1').on('click', function() {
        $('#myModalok').modal({
          show: true
        });
    });

    $('#butt2').on('click', function() {
      $('#mbodyko').load('nav.html', function() {
        $('#myModalnok').modal({
          show: true
        });
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is that the loaded data from `nav.html` have IDs that are in the original html DOM, or `index.html` and you can't have a page with two elements that have the same ID, or it will not work properly.